# How to launch an application after a specific Disc was mounted using Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I'm newbie in [Automator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)). There are many [examples](https://www.raywenderlich.com/58986/automator-for-mac-tutorial-and-examples) for simple actions.

But I could not find examples or [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2488) for launching some applications after a specific disk was mounted. It will be very useful at work.

Has someone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36475943/3226984) great answer.
Just follow 4 simple steps.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on ShooTerKo's answer on Stack Overflow (the one Volodymyr Kulyk links to) I've written the following script that continues the Workflow if the triggeringVolumeName is found. That way the actual launch (or any other Workflow action) can be moved outside the Applescript:

1. Create a new Automator action of type **Folder Action**
2. Choose the **Volumes** folder of your system as input by clicking **Other...** in the **Choose folder** dropdown, pressing **Cmd+Shift+G** and typing `/Volumes`
3. As first action choose **Execute Applescript**
4. Use the following script and change `YOUR_VOLUME_NAME` to match your needs:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       -- define the volume name and the application to start
       set triggeringVolumeName to "YOUR_VOLUME_NAME"

       -- walk through all newly mounted volumes
       repeat with aMountedVolumeAlias in input

           -- get the volume name from the given alias
           tell application "System Events" to set mountedVolumeName to name of aMountedVolumeAlias

           -- compare the volume name with the defined trigger name
           if mountedVolumeName is triggeringVolumeName then

               -- continue workflow
               return input

           end if

       end repeat

       -- if repeat finished without match, cancel workflow
       error number -128

   end run
   ```
5. Add other actions to the Workflow, e.g. **Ask for Confirmation**, **Copy Finder Items** or **Launch Application**

Answer (score 0):

Open Automator and create a new folder action.

Choose a folder to watch. In my example it's a Mavericks installer thumb drive with the name *SystemUSBMav*.

Then add *Launch Application* from the Automator's library and choose an application to launch.

Save the folder action as *Launch on Mount*.

[image: Folder Action]

---

A second approach is a launch agent:

Create a file *local.user.mountonlaunch.plist* in ~/Library/LaunchAgents with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.user.mountonlaunch</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
        <string>/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes/SystemUSBMav</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Load the file with:

```
launchctl load /Users/user_name/Library/LaunchAgents/local.user.mountonlaunch.plist
```

---

The downside of both approaches is that the application will be launched also after ejecting the disk/volume or modifying files in the root of the volume. You may circumnavigate the latter by creating a locked, "fake" watch folder on the volume.